# Installation of Zeromq in windows for python

Tags: python, windows, installation, zeromq

I'm trying to install zeromq in windows7. I'm following the instructions given in the documents of zeromq: http://zeromq.org/docs:windows-installations

When I enter this command

```
python setup.py configure --zmq=../libzmq
```

I get this error

```
sh.exe : python: command not found.
```

How to solve this error and install zmq in windows?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add python to your path environment variable. This will fix the installation error.